# Netbeans bagunçando acentuação

Tags: netbeans

De uns dias pra cá, notei que o Netbeans anda trocando caracteres acentuados em meu código.
Aparentemente, ele só faz isso na classe que ficou aberta quando fechei o Netbeans.
Ou seja, estou editando duas classes e fecho o Netbeans. Quando reabro, a classe que está em evidência (aberta) está com os caracteres acentuados bagunçados.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("MÃªs/Ano invÃ¡lido!"));
```

- Netbeans 8.0.1
- Windows 7 64bits
- Codificação do código fonte: UTF-8

O que pode ser isso?

Comment: Opa, clicando com o botão direito no seu projeto, no menu `Properties`, o `encoding` também está setado para `UTF-8`?

Comment: Sim, também está UTF-8

Comment: Notei que estas alterações ocorrem apenas nas classes Java, no XHTML não acontece. Notei tmb que qdo abro o Netbeans e noto que as acentuações foram alteradas, posso fechar a classe e reiniciar o Netbeans e reabrir a classe que o código com acentos errados não foi "gravado"

Comment: Cara, muito estranho. Uma tentativa possível é apagar a pasta `%HOMEPATH%\.nbi` (isso vai resetar as configurações do Netbeans), talvez até mesmo reinstalar o IDE ou fazer um *downgrade*. Outra coisa é tentar apagar qualquer arquivos proprietários específicos do Netbeans no Projeto e "reimportar" o código do projeto para dentro. Isso tem cara de configuração corrompida ou algum plugin que azedou o IDE.

Comment: Já tentou setar o charset como UTF-8 no arquivo de configuração do NetBeans? Se não me engano é só adicionar o parâmetro `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` na opção `netbeans_default_options` dentro do arquivo `$DIRETORIO_NETBEANS/etc/netbeans.conf`.

Comment: Alguns outros diretórios que são bons candidatos a serem apagados `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache` e `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans`.

Comment: @gabrielhof Parece que você matou a charada! Obrigado tmb ao Anthony Accioly

Comment: Hehe, posta a resposta para pessoas com esse mesmo problema :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme a dica do @gabrielhof, adicionei o parâmetro <kbd>-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</kbd> na opção <kbd>netbeans_default_options</kbd> do arquivo de configuração do NetBeans <kbd>$DIRETORIO_NETBEANS/etc/netbeans.conf</kbd>

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Realmente funciona.

Comment: Além da adição do parâmetro acima, também instalei um versão atualizada do visualizador HTML do netbeans baixado deste link: http://plugins.netbeans.org/download/plugin/3675

Comment: Também estava com o mesmo problema, inserindo essa linha no arquivo de configuração resolveu, obrigado galera!

Answer (score -3):

Resolvi trocando a JDK após o projeto já ter aberto. Cliquei com botão direito no projeto e depois propriedade-biblioteca e depois troquei o JDK no meu caso para 1.8