# Porque o Eclipse e o Netbeans estragam arquivos com acentuação?

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans

Olha, tentei e tentei, procurei na web alguma forma de aprender a usar essas ferramentas, mas estou desistindo, vou utilizar o Notepad++ mesmo.
Antes eu utilizava o Dreanweaver e nunca tive esse problema.

Uso sempre UTF-8 tanto na criação do arquivo como no html

Só pra constar o notepad++ não "estraga" o arquivo.

Eu sempre trabalhei com UTF-8 no dreanweaver eu quero usar o Netbeans ou Eclipse, mas está impossível.

Comment: Muito provavelmente por que você não setou a codificação correta, ao criar o projeto.

Comment: É provavel que seu arquivos foram criados com o enconde ANSI, ISO-8859 ou algum outro e o padrão do workspace(eclipse) está como utf-8, é possível mudar essa configuração.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque qual é o enconde dos arquivos 'estragados' e o encode padrão do eclipse.

Comment: Pior que já fiz tudo quanto é teste e mudança que o netbeans permite, crio e salvo o arquivo como UTF8 que é o que sempre usei no Dreanweaver, mas do nada ele simplesmente muda os caracteres acentuados para códigos ilegiveis... simplesmente sozinho...

Comment: Esse problema acontece sempre com arquivos já criados ou com novos?

Comment: Se eu criar um arquivo, trabalho com ele numa boa... então abro outro arquivo pra trabalhar... beleza... quando volto pro arquivo anterior, lá está ele todo "zuado", ou seja tanto faz, pode ser novo ou já existente.

Comment: Talvez não seja o netbeans, pode ser o seu php como conecta no banco, leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 (leia a parte sobre header, PDO e Mysqli).

Comment: Não é na hora de exibir no navegador, ele altera o arquivo fisicamente mesmo... ele troca os acentos por caracteres de maquina vou colocar aqui vamos ver se o editor deixa olha <html dir="ltr"><head>
        <title>PÃƒÂ¡gina</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body contenteditable="true">
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    

</body></html>

Comment: Acho que tem um bug no editor HTML do Netbeans, quando visualizo a pagina e volto para o código ele detona o arquivo veja: PÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¡gina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, tente remover os caracteres "estragados" e salve o documento. Tive este problema em arquivos com codificação diferente da padrão do **NetBeans**.

Outra recomendação é informar ao site (tanto na parte **HTML** tanto na parte **PHP**) a codificação utilizada, na qual o navegador poderá efetuar as conversões corretas na hora de exibir os textos caso tenha problemas com acentuação na visualização do site.

## EDIT

Pode encontrar sua resposta [neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33712/netbeans-bagun%C3%A7ando-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o?rq=1) aqui, o qual um membro postou a solução.

Comment: Então Gabriel, eu adicionei o parametro conforme a dica no tópico que sugeriu e realmente parou de bagunçar, porem o editor html do netbeans insiste em mudar a estrutura do arquivo, ele simplesmente substitui parte do código de '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>' por '<html dir="ltr">' então só pode ser um bug, vou aguardar a correção.